Sybase ASE SQL query to create a field from system tables that shows the size of each table in MB(s)
I am able to get the row count using system tables, also I want to include a field that shows the size of each table in MB(s).
I tried the below query to get the table row count.
declare @kernel_mode varchar(15)
if @@trancount = 0
begin
    set chained off
end

set transaction isolation level 1

select @kernel_mode = @@kernelmode

select
ob.name as Table_Name, 
ob.type as Type, 
ta.rowcnt as Row_Count,  
ob.crdate as Created_Date, 
ta.statmoddate as Last_Modified_Date
into #t
from sysobjects ob, systabstats ta 
where ob.type="U"
and ta.id=ob.id
order by ob.name

if (@kernel_mode = 'process')
    begin
        exec sp_autoformat @fulltabname = #t,
        @selectlist = "Table_Name, Type, Row_Count, Created_Date, Last_Modified_Date",
        @orderby = "order by Table_Name asc"
    end
    else
    begin
        exec sp_autoformat @fulltabname = #t,
        @selectlist = "Table_Name, Type, Row_Count, Created_Date, Last_Modified_Date",
        @orderby = "order by Table_Name asc"
    end

  drop table #t


are you referring to reserved or used space? depending on your ASE version and the level of accuracy you're looking for I'd suggest reviewing the source code for sp_spaceused and sp_spaceusage to see where they obtain their data - from here you should be able to write your custom queries; also, have you looked at the various page count columns in systabstats to see if they could be of use?

Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check the two store procs you mentioned. I already checked the systabstats, but I couldn't find anything useful for table size.

table size will need to be calculated based on number of data and index pages; are you saying systabstats.pagecnt is wrong/inaccurate?

actually it worked, I was doing it wrong earlier. I just calculated the pagecnt and pagesize (pagecnt*@@pagesize/1024*1024) and I got the total table size in MB

But, it is only working on tables in master database, and I am getting 'Arithmetic overflow occured' when I ran the same query on other databases.

you want to multiply by @@maxpagesize (one of 2K / 4K / 8K / 16K) and not @@pagesize (always 2K); try (pagecnt * @@maxpagesize / 1024 / 1024) to calculate MB; if you're still hitting 'arithmetic overflow' errors try converting pagecnt to bigint during the calculations (this should force ASE to process the calculation as bigint instead of the default int)

as for the query only working in the master database ... sounds like you're running your query from within the master database;  make sure you're either a) sitting in the desired database (eg, use dbname) prior to running the query or b) preference all table references with the database name (eg, instead of sysobjects use dbname..sysobjects)

I meant, the query ran on master database with no errors, and I got arithmetic overflow in other databases. But, now it's working fine, thanks for the suggestions.

As per @markp-fuso suggestions, I have come up with the below query.
declare @kernel_mode varchar(15)
if @@trancount = 0
begin
    set chained off
end

set transaction isolation level 1

select @kernel_mode = @@kernelmode

select
ob.name as Table_Name, 
ob.type as Type, 
ta.rowcnt as Row_Count,  
(cast(ta.pagecnt as 
bigint)*@@maxpagesize/1024.0/1024.0 as 
Table_Size_in_MB
ob.crdate as Created_Date, 
ta.statmoddate as Last_Modified_Date
into #t
from sysobjects ob, systabstats ta 
where ob.type="U"
and ta.id=ob.id
order by ob.name

if (@kernel_mode = 'process')
    begin
        exec sp_autoformat @fulltabname = #t,
        @select list ="Table_Name, Type, 
Row_Count, Table_Size_in_MB, Created_Date, 
Last_Modified_Date",
        @orderby = "order by Table_Name asc"
    end
    else
    begin
        exec sp_autoformat @fulltabname = #t,
        @selectlist = "Table_Name, Type, 
Row_Count, Table_Size_in_MB, Created_Date, 
Last_Modified_Date",
        @orderby = "order by Table_Name asc"
    end

